# Can every proper subset of a uncountable set be countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Can every proper subset of uncountable set be countable? If yes, is there any example of it?

If every proper subset of uncountable set is countable, could then there be no injection from the uncountable set to any of its proper subset? Then would that uncountable set be not infinite and not finite?

Comment: Every set is a subset of itself!

Comment: Please do not just upload a problem. Say what you have tried, and what results you can use. You already have posed good questions before.

Comment: @user977780 Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited the question.

Comment: The punchline is that although an uncountable set might contain some countable subsets... the vast majority of its subsets will also be uncountable.  Take as an explicit example $\Bbb R$ as your uncountable set, the set of real numbers.  Well... the set of nonzero real numbers is a proper subset of $\Bbb R$ and is also uncountable.  You can use this idea for a more general proof.

Comment: How much choice are we assuming here?

Comment: Suppose our original uncountable set was $X$ and take $A$ as an example nonempty proper subset of $X$.  If we were to assume a hypothesis that every proper subset of $X$ were countable, then $A$ would be countable.  So too would be $X\setminus A$.  But then $X = A\cup (X\setminus A)$ is equal to the union of two countable sets and by theorem would also then be countable... a contradiction.

Comment: Even without AC, this is false, as the comments by JMoravitz point out. The theorem $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ does not use AC, so the $A\cup(X\setminus A)$ example does not need AC. Perhaps it's worth pointing out, though, that there are models of ZF without AC in which we can have an uncountable set that is a countable union of countable sets.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you restrict to proper subsets, this isn't true.

If $X$ is an infinite set, and $x \in X$, $X-\{x\}$ has the same cardinality as $X$. To see this, use Axiom of Choice to pick a countably infinite subset of {x_1,x_2,...,} of $X$. Define a mapping $f : X \rightarrow X-\{x\}$ by, $f(x) = x_1, f(x_i) = x_{i+1}$ for all $i = 1,2,3,...$ and $f(y) = y$ for all $y \neq x, x_i$. $f$ is a bijection.

The above statement applied inductively to a finite subset $F$ of $X$ shows that $X-F$ has the same cardinality as $X$.

---

In fact, if $X$ is an uncountable and $\{C_i\}$ is a countable collection of countable subsets of $X$, then $X-\cup_i C_i$ is uncountable (otherwise, a countable union of countable sets would be uncountable, contradiction).